# Problem with powershell BitsTransfers using asynchronous flag

Tags: powershell, bit, powershell-5.0

I am running powershell 5 
I am trying to learn to download files in the background to suppress the progress bar using BITS but I am having some issues.

When I download the test file with the Asynchronous flag the files downloads but instead of downloading the 10MB.zip file it just generates a randomly named tmp file with the 10 MB file. It's like it downloaded the file but it can't rename it.

If I remove the  Asynchronous flag it will download perfectly but I get the progress bar which is what I am trying to suppress

Here is a demo of the code I am using

Import-Module BitsTransfer

Start-BitsTransfer -Source http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip -Destination $PSScriptRoot -Asynchronous

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, you need to complete the transfer, when using asynchronous transfer.

```
$Job = Start-BitsTransfer -Source https://Server1.TrustedDomain.com/File1.zip `
       -Destination d:\temp\downloads\ -Asynchronous

while (($Job.JobState -eq "Transferring") -or ($Job.JobState -eq "Connecting")) `
       { sleep 5;} # Poll for status, sleep for 5 seconds, or perform an action.

Switch($Job.JobState)
{
    "Transferred" {Complete-BitsTransfer -BitsJob $Job}
    "Error" {$Job | Format-List } # List the errors.
    default {"Other action"} #  Perform corrective action.
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bits/using-windows-powershell-to-create-bits-transfer-jobs